# Does the SVM require lots of features most of the time?

Tags: svm, feature-construction

So I know about the curse of dimensionality (too many features too less data).

Say I have a 3000 sample dataset, would 3 features be too less?

Comment: It depends on the informativeness of your features. There's only one way to find out; it should not take much time with your small data set.

Comment: I like the implicit suggestion in your comment, "GTFO off the internet and go train the SVM"

Answer (score -4, accepted):

So I'll post an answer to my own question. For anyone who comes across this post during the feature selection / More features or less process, I dont know what you can do (well except if you're on python then mork's answer has a good way to do feature selection there) but I can tell you what NOT to do.

Do not under any circumstances ever "try" determining best features by training+testing the SVM / statistical model. That is oh this feature works because of more classification accuracy than the other one. NO. Not unless that is the *only* way left, dont do it. That is a way, you are free to do it, but if you can try something else please do. Dont listen to anyone who tells you to do that

How many features your problem requires depends on how many optimal features you can *find*. I'll leave it at that. How to find them? That is the million dollar question.

Edit:

People are getting confused. When you dont know about the accuracy of your features, it is bad practice to "train" data to see how many features your SVM needs. For that it is better you select features on the basis of some criteria set by *your* problem. If you want after that, *then* you *may* try feature selection techniques. But remember, reducing too many dimensions may also decrease accuracy sometimes.

Comment: This answer lacks substance and uses a lot of words to say "I don't know."

Comment: It also says what NOT to do, like trying out classification results manually to select features all the time when there could be alternatives

Comment: Yes, but stepwise variable selection is a perfectly valid approach so that point was wrong too.

Comment: Yes it may be but not when you dont know if your features are 100% correct, it will give an erraneous result. For that you do other things, which is what this question adresses. You should only do that when you are absolutely sure about your data!

Comment: The nature of applied statistics and machine learning is that you can never know if your features are 100% or even "mostly" correct. Nearly all real-world data has noise to some degree that cannot be avoided. On the other hand, if a feature is completely useless (e.g., taken from a random number generator) then it goes without saying that you'll have to rely on something else. If that's what you were trying to say, then that's not a useful/insightful answer either.

Comment: Yes noise is there upto some extent and that is not what I'm saying. This problem is usually faced by people who're new to the field and will also be searched for by people who're most likely novices, because people at that stage are still learning (like me), the problem they'll be looking online for a solution for will be the _integrity_ of their features. Doing piecewise classification over wrong features and getting a "temporary" result which you cannot replicate does not help at all, so that's what I'm saying, let it be the last option if any. How you'll determine the integrity is upto you

Comment: It depends on the problem you're working on, it cannot be decided by the classifier

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon some rules of thumb for dataset sizes, but not specific to the ratio of features / samples.

Also, it seems easier to guess to the "positive" side, i.e. "might it work?" then "might it fail?". 
I witnessed both small datasets (<1000) that functioned well with even 20-50 features, and huge datasets (~10M) that functioned well with very few (<5) features.

The stage in the processing pipeline to tackle this, is the [feature selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection) one. I'd start with gathering all of your make-sense features and playing with different k-best values for the feature selection object to find. (ranges like: 10, 50, 100, ..)

You didn't mention a specific research environment, but I'd like to suggest scikit-learn [sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) running inside a [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) pipeline. This way the grid object will help you choose the closest k-best featues out of a given list. Something like:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

pipe = []
pipe.append(SelectKBest())
pipe.append(LinearSVC())

est_pipe = make_pipeline(*pipe)
print 'all possible grid params: {0}'.format(est_pipe.get_params().keys())
param_grid = {
  # some svc grid params..,
  'selectkbest__k': [5, 10, 50, 100]
}

grid = GridSearchCV(est_pipe, param_grid=param_grid)
grid.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Looks like someone managed to pull the selected feature list out of an OpenCV object, using inheritance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962349/how-do-i-use-adaboost-for-feature-selection. The estimator there was adaboost, though

Comment: I've come across it before, adaboost is unlikely overhead for the data I have, plus I just wanted to know if very small feature vectors can be used for large samples (this is partially due to my own very strange results)

Comment: @astroman, since the question was asked in a general way - would you consider marking this as the right answer? if not, I'd consider editing the question and tags so that others understand the context better

Comment: No, I didn't say anything before but I'll do so now. My question was "Does the SVM require lots of features most of the time?", or "In general how many features does your SVM require?". I answered this in my own answer. 

My question was not, "I'm trying to do feature selection in python, I've done this much, please help me with how to move this forward from this point, using scikit-learn." or "How to do feature selection in SVM using OpenCV / C++/ python?"